# Specify argument in dplyr function using character variable

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I'm trying to use dplyr `left_join` to merge two df whose key-column name name are different.
If I use the sintax specifyed by help I can do as follow:

```
aaa<- data.frame(
  a = 1:10,
  b = letters[1:10]
)

bbb <- data.frame(
  c = 1:15,
  d = LETTERS[15:1]
)

aaa_join_bbb <- aaa %>%
  left_join(bbb, by = c("a" = "c"))
```

The outcome is what i expected but now I'm trying to do the same using variables in which I stored the names of the colum to use to performe merge. Consider the following lines:

```
key_aaa <- "a"
key_bbb <- "c"

aaa_join_bbb <- aaa %>%
  left_join(bbb, by = c(key_aaa = key_bbb))
```

In this second case R give back an error... I have seen many post on similar question but I wasn't able to solve. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Maël's answer, using `setNames`

```r
aaa_join_bbb <- aaa %>%
    left_join(bbb, by = setNames(key_bbb, key_aaa))
```